# Is hitchhiking permitted in the Faroe Islands?

Tags: legal, planning, hitchhiking, denmark, faroe-islands

I'm planning to go to the Faroe Islands next August after visiting Iceland.

I was wondering if hitchhiking is permitted anywhere in the Faroe Islands.
I've checked the hitchwiki website, but it doesn't say if is legal or not.

Comment: Arctictern, it's been seven months so I assume you have made your trip. Would you be interested to document here what you found in terms of hitchhiking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Faroe Islands are [officially part of Denmark](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Faeroe_Islands) (albeit self-governing).

[According to Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Denmark#By_thumb), it's legal to hitch in Denmark, apart from on motorways:

> Destination boards are recommended. For safety reasons, it is illegal
>   to hitchhike on the expressways, so it is better to use the on ramps
>   and service areas. When crossing by ferry, try to get into a car that
>   already paid for the ticket.

This is backed up in [this table of countries](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tips_for_hitchhiking#Countries) which states that it's generally rare, but easy, legal and you're not usually expected to pay for the ride.

Comment: The Faroe Islands are an autonomous country within the Kingdom of Denmark and as such have their own laws regarding internal matters and not those passed by the Danish parliament. I believe you are correct, that it is legal to hitchhike in the Faroe Islands, but you can't fully support that argument by citing Danish law.

Comment: Hmm, I was basing that off the article on Hitchwiki (updated to include link to quote). Reading up on it, they've gradually taken over various internal matters, but initially laws were simply Danish, and now have been adapted.  Well spotted.  I do feel that Hitchwiki would have split them out if they were different, however - they're pretty accurate on that.  I'll keep looking for more evidence.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that there are any legal regulations on hitchhiking, neither in Denmark nor on the Faroe Islands. Motorways in Denmark are not accessible to pedestrians and it is illegal to stop when driving a vehicle (unless required by the traffic situation), so it is rather the requirements (a vehicle stops to pick up a pedestrian) for hitchhiking which are prohibited and not hitchhiking itself.

Comment: @MarkMayo: HitchWiki is super casual compared to Wikipedia or Wiktionary or WikiVoyage. There's tons of stuff missing until somebody goes and hitchhikes there then shares the information. So there could be this reason for Hitchwiki not splitting them out if they are in fact different.